# ElasticsearchSinkConnector can't connect to Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using the [kafka-lenses-dev](https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-lenses-dev) image, I ran into problems connecting Kafka to the local Elasticsearch 7.1.1 instance. As you can see, the connection is refused, although the instance is up and running and it's possible to curl docs in. Is the version of Elastic problematic for the connector or is the config wrong?

Config

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
type.name=kafka-connect
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
topics=cc_data
name=elastic-sink
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
connection.url=http://localhost:9200
key.ignore=true
```

Error

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Couldn't start ElasticsearchSinkTask due to connection error:
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:147)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:114)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:120)
...
Caused by: io.searchbox.client.config.exception.CouldNotConnectException: Could not connect to http://localhost:9200
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:60)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getServerVersion(JestElasticsearchClient.java:168)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:145)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've specified Elasticsearch as being at `localhost:9200`. Unless Elasticsearch is running *on the same container as Kafka Connect* then this hostname is wrong. You need to specify the hostname of Elasticsearch in a form that is reachable from where Kafka Connect is running.

As an example, you can see an example of how to configure this based on [this Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/ksql-atm-fraud-detection/docker-compose.yml) [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/ksql-atm-fraud-detection/scripts/create-es-sink.sh).

Comment: Thanks, that was the hint I needed! As I'm currently running elastic for testing purposes as a local instance instead of within docker, I just had to replace localhost:9200 with host.docker.internal:9200